# Angular Displaying a Table with a Condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

In my code, I have a JSON list which I fetch a data using fromFetch(). I can get the data and group it on the console by categoryId. I want to display a table of products only with the categoryId of 2. Right now, I can only display a uniform table without the condition I want. What should I do to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="items$ | async"
    class="mat-elevation-z8"
    matSort
  >
    <ng-container matColumnDef="categoryId">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Category Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.categoryId }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
items$: Observable<Item[]>;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Item>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['categoryId', 'name'];

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.items$ = fromFetch(
      'someitems/data/items.json'
    ).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
    );

    this.items$.subscribe(function (result) {
      const grouped = _.groupBy(result, (res) => res.categoryId);
      this.dataSource = result;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      console.log(grouped);
    });
  }
```

Comment: this may help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping-xd2utk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend current `items$` observable, to perform further operation using another `map` operator. Apply your object transformation logic in `map` function.

**Update**

On the template side you had to add a separate row for groupBy row, right? You can use the `when` clause on another `mat-row`. Inside when clause you can add `isGroup` function, that helps to verify whether to show the `groupBy` row or not.

**Template**

```
<tr mat-row 
  *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['initial']; when: isGroup"
></tr>
```

**TS**

```
isGroup(index, item): boolean {
  return item.isGroupBy;
}

this.items$ = fromFetch(
  'someitems/data/items.json'
).pipe(
  switchMap((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }),
  map((data) => {
    const grouped = groupBy(data, (res) => res.categoryId);
    let output = [];
    for (let group in grouped) {
      output.push({ initial: group, isGroupBy: true });
      output = output.concat(grouped[group]);
    }
    return output;
  })
);
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader-umqp4w)

Comment: hi thank you, but I also wnt to have a seperate list for categoryId = 3 and 4. How can I do that?

Comment: @RocketMonkey do you need records to be displayed in grouped format on mat-table?

Comment: my main goal is that actually yes, I want t o group items by categoryId but, angular material tqable doesn't really support grouping so, I decided to go with having multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function as data source argument

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="fetch(2) | async" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
```

and the function will look something like:

```
fetch(catId): MatTableDataSource<Item>{
  const data = this.items$.filter(row => row.categoryId === catId);
  const ds = new MatTableDataSource<Item>(data);
  ds.paginator = this.paginator;
  ds.sort = this.sort;

  return ds;
}
```